# Did Cordova Replace PhoneGap

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am using OSX 10.8, and XCode 4.41.  I went through and installed Cordova from the PhoneGap site.  Went through the getting started part of the PhoneGap site.  I successfully installed Cordova and launched it on the iPhone simulator.  My question is do I just add my app ( example: index.html, associated js and css files) to the www folder? and is there a phonegap.js or .jar file, or any other files I need to add to the application to be able to compile it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name got changed from PhoneGap to Cordova because of legal reasons with Adobe now owning the trademark on PhoneGap. If you had previously used phonegap.js and phonegap.jar they are now cordova.js and cordoava.jar with the version numbers included.

Cordova will be the src distribution from Apache and PhoneGap will be the downstream binary distribution available from phonegap.com.

Comment: So it seems they are forking into 2 different projects.  Which one do you think is going to be a better one to follow?

Comment: Let me be clear this is not a fork. All of us PG developers contribute to the Apache repo. The official source code will be hosted by Apache. Apache only does source code releases so in order to make it easier for devs we also build the src released from Apache and post on phonegap.com. So in effect when you see a 2.1 src release from Apache and a 2.1 release from PhoneGap.com the only difference is the libraries/jars etc are already built for you at PhoneGap.com.